# Compiler can't find instance of derived typeclass when result is assigned to val

Tags: scala, shapeless

I have following question: having typeclass for ADT derived with `LabelledTypeClassCompanion` (where both *product* and *coproduct* are correctly defined) inside Scala object, why compiler can't find instance for datatype itself (coproduct), but is able to do so for parameters of specific data constructors (product) when called inside the same object and assigned to `val`?

Below is a snippet for `Show` typeclass which is mostly borrowed from corresponding *Shapeless* [example](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/d59463a0c093a21345754226702cbd807015b6ca/examples/src/main/scala/shapeless/examples/derivation.scala):

```scala
import shapeless._

object ShowGeneric {

  trait Show[T] {
    def show(t: T): String
  }

  object Show extends LabelledTypeClassCompanion[Show] {

    implicit def intShow: Show[Int] = new Show[Int] {
      override def show(i: Int): String = i.toString
    }

    implicit def booleanShow: Show[Boolean] = new Show[Boolean] {
      override def show(b: Boolean): String = b.toString
    }

    implicit def listShow[A](implicit showA: Show[A]): Show[List[A]] = new Show[List[A]] {
      override def show(l: List[A]): String = l.map(showA.show).mkString("List(", ", ", ")")
    }

    object typeClass extends LabelledTypeClass[Show] {
      override def emptyProduct: Show[HNil] = new Show[HNil] {
        override def show(t: HNil): String = ""
      }

      override def product[H, T <: HList](name: String, sh: Show[H], st: Show[T]): Show[H :: T] = new Show[H :: T] {
        override def show(t: H :: T): String = {
          val head = s"$name = ${sh.show(t.head)}"
          val tail = st.show(t.tail)
          if(tail.isEmpty) head else s"$head, $tail"
        }
      }

      override def coproduct[L, R <: Coproduct](name: String, cl: => Show[L], cr: => Show[R]): Show[L :+: R] = new Show[L :+: R] {
        override def show(t: L :+: R): String = t match {
          case Inl(l) => s"$name(${cl.show(l)})"
          case Inr(r) => cr.show(r)
        }
      }

      override def emptyCoproduct: Show[CNil] = new Show[CNil] {
        override def show(t: CNil): String = ""
      }

      override def project[F, G](instance: => Show[G], to: F => G, from: G => F): Show[F] = new Show[F] {
        override def show(t: F): String = instance.show(to(t))
      }
    }
  }

  implicit class ShowOps[T](t: T)(implicit showT: Show[T]) {
    def show: String = showT.show(t)
  }

  sealed trait Whatever
  case class IntBool(i: Int, b: Boolean) extends Whatever
  case class BoolInt(b: Boolean, i: Int) extends Whatever
  case class BoolListInt(b: Boolean, l: List[Int]) extends Whatever

  def showWhatever(whatever: Whatever)(implicit showWhatever: Show[Whatever]): String = {
    showWhatever.show(whatever)
  }

  val stringBoolInt = BoolInt(false, 100).show // Compiles
  val stringShowWhatever = showWhatever(BoolInt(false, 100)) // Doesn't compile: could not find implicit value for parameter showWhatever:ShowGeneric.Show[ShowGeneric.Whatever]
}
```

Thanks in advance for your answers!

Comment: Hmm, this works as written if you either define `Whatever` or call `showWatever` outside of the object. I think I remember running into something like this before, but don't have specifics.

Comment: Exactly, no problem with it when called outside.

Comment: `-Xlog-implicits` says `Sealed trait trial.ShowGeneric.Whatever has no case class subtypes` which might be https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7755 which it attempts to work around.